# What is the most efficient/fastest way to use a jQuery selector multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an HTML element that I select and manipulate multiple times within a function using the jQuery selector `$("#main-nav)`.

Would it be faster to assign the jQuery object returned by `$("#main-nav")` to a variable at the start of the function, and to manipulate it using that variable?

Even if it's not significantly faster, is it best practice to do so anyway?

In short - which of the 2 functions below is faster and/or exhibits best practices?

```js
//MOBILE MENU ANIMATION
$("#menu-icon").click(function() {
  $("#main-nav").toggleClass("display");
  if ($("#main-nav").hasClass("display")) {
    $("#main-nav").velocity("transition.slideDownBigIn", {
      duration: 300
    });
  } else {
    $("#main-nav").velocity("transition.slideUpBigOut", {
      duration: 300
    });
  }
});
```

OR

```js
//MOBILE MENU ANIMATION
$("#menu-icon").click(function() {
  var navMenu = $("#main-nav");
  navMenu.toggleClass("display");
  if (navMenu.hasClass("display")) {
    navMenu.velocity("transition.slideDownBigIn", {
      duration: 300
    });
  } else {
    navMenu.velocity("transition.slideUpBigOut", {
      duration: 300
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: A JQuery selector with an ID as in your example does not "cost" much, but they are still not as efficient as remembering the returned object. And once you've got "expensive" selectors like `$("div.container > div > table > tr > td.some-class")` you might really have an impact on performance. Better always work with a variable if you're accessing the same object multiple times.

Comment: speed is irrelevant here, but repeating strings anywhere in your program violates the DRY principle. The common practice here is to store it as a variable.

Comment: The second example is *caching* the selector `$('#main-nav')` in a sense, eliminating the need to traverse the DOM thereafter with each additional instance of `$("#main-nav")`. Speed is rarely an issue anymore as JavaScript interpreters are immenesly fast. You'd really have to splatter some spaghetti all over your screen to create JS functionality that's painfully slow. tl;dr option 2 is the way to go for reasons already stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter how much jQuery could be optimised for this particular case, it must still process the selector string each time it is called (even if it were to just check that it's the same as the previously used selector). The version using a variable avoids this cost, and so would of course be more efficient.

As far as best practice goes, it's always better to store the result in a variable in a case like this. The only reason to call the same function multiple times with the same input is if you expect the result to change, or the function to have certain side effects. On the flip side, if you require the function to give you the same result each time, and don't care/don't want it's side effects to occur multiple times, then you *must* store the result.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is both faster, since it only traverses the DOM once, and best practice, because anything that eliminates redundency in code is almost always preferable.

Also note that it's customary (but not important at all) to prefix jQuery selectors/objects with a $:

```
var $navMenu = $("#main-nav");
```

**Edit:** Expanded on answer.

Comment: "*The second one is both faster and best practice.*" Why? Faster how? Better practice why?

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget of jQuery chain.

```
$("#menu-icon").click(function() {
  //var navMenu = //survive without it
  $("#main-nav")
    .toggleClass(function(){
       //optionally var $this = $(this);
       $(this).hasClass("display") ? 
         $(this).velocity("transition.slideUpBigOut", {duration: 300}) :
         $(this).velocity("transition.slideUpBigIn", {duration: 300});
       return "display";
     });
/*
  if (navMenu.hasClass("display")) {
    navMenu.velocity("transition.slideDownBigIn", {
      duration: 300
    });
  } else {
    navMenu.velocity("transition.slideUpBigOut", {
      duration: 300
    });
  }
*/
});
```